# Не получается обратится к [HttpPut] методу в конролере

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Сабж. Есть такой метод в контролере.

```cs
[HttpPut]
public void Put([FromBody] string json)
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        // var domain = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Domain>(json);

        // db.Domain.Update(domain);
        // db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Делаю запросы через postman с телом

```json
{
  "Name": "0008.app",
  "CMS": null,
  "TryChek": null,
  "InProgress": true
}
```

И не попадаю в метод, получаю ошибку

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status": 415,
  "traceId": "00-6a6f0c1cb891f3fda89a568437d5195f-016d67432db7e656-00"
}
```

Я пробовал все типы данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я уберу параметр `[FromBody] string json` и просто сделаю PUT запрос то попаду в метод. Как мне отправить мой json в этот метод?

Comment: Вы просите строку, а не объект или JSON. Условно, от вас ожидается просто `"значение"`.  Сделайте класс, в котором будут свойства, описывающие ваш JSON объект, и его используйте в запросе. `public class MyItem { public string Name { get; set; } }`... `Put([FromBody] MyItem item) { var name = item.Name; }`. В вашем коде вижу, что вы десериализуете потом в `Domain`, вот этот класс и используйте в параметрах метода, за вас автоматом десериализует все ASP.

Comment: Спасибо, оформите как ответ пожалуйста что бы я отметил.

Comment: Не хочу) Можете сделать это самостоятельно, написав подробно как решили.

Comment: Почти каждый вопрос вам редактирую по одной и той же причине, вы вставляете код через HTML сниппеты, в результате чего выглядит оно плохо и подсветки синтаксиса нет, плюс отступы в коде как попало. Научитесь это делать правильно.